# Rails rake task doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I try add file random.rake to my `/lib/tasks` folder but after that when i type `rake -T` I don't see `rake random` on the list. I try save few files but without any results.

```
task :greet do
   puts "How are you?"
end
```

I have ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2.13 rake 10.1.0

What I can do?

Comment: The task name is used, i.e. look for `rake greet`

Comment: after change name nothing happen, same problem

Comment: See vencislaf's answer below, or use `rake -T -A` to shows all tasks, including uncommented ones.

Comment: this doesn't mean it doesn't work (if you run it, it will still run), it just means it isn't in the list.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add some description to your task:

```
desc "Some description here"
task :greet do
  puts "How are you?"
end
```

Easy way to check the presence of the task if you have many tasks:

```
$ rake -T | grep greet
```

Comment: ok, its on the list but after that

rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'great'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Comment: You have typo. It's not "great", it is "greet".

Comment: @vencislaf you don't need grep, just `rake -T greet`

Comment: @Stefan, you are right. I am just used to search in my tasks with `grep` because it will filter them by their description too :)